# Tensorflow, tf.reshape causes "Gradients do not exist for variables"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm writing a fully connected layer using Tensorflow/Keras (TF version 2.1, Python 3.7 on Windows), but I've found that if I reshape my weights tensor before multiplying by it then Tensorflow doesn't seem to be able to calculate the gradient even if I just reshape to its own shape. Consider the following layer code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class FCLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,output_size,cause_error = False):
        super(FCLayer,self).__init__()
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.cause_error = cause_error

    def build(self,input_shape): 
        self.input_size = input_shape[1]        
        weights = self.add_weight(shape=(self.input_size,
                                         self.output_size),
                                 initializer='random_normal',
                                 trainable=True)

        if self.cause_error:
            self.weights2 = tf.reshape( weights,
                                        shape = (self.input_size,
                                                 self.output_size))
        else:
            self.weights2 = weights

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.weights2)
```

If this is used with cause_error = True, then I get the following output when training on mnist for 4 epochs (specific training code included below):

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/4
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['sequential/dummy_layer/Variable:0'] when minimizing the loss.
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['sequential/dummy_layer/Variable:0'] when minimizing the loss.
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 20us/sample - loss: 2.4131 - accuracy: 0.0722 - val_loss: 2.3963 - val_accuracy: 0.0834
Epoch 2/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 12us/sample - loss: 2.4122 - accuracy: 0.0722 - val_loss: 2.3953 - val_accuracy: 0.0836
Epoch 3/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 12us/sample - loss: 2.4112 - accuracy: 0.0724 - val_loss: 2.3944 - val_accuracy: 0.0838
Epoch 4/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 13us/sample - loss: 2.4102 - accuracy: 0.0725 - val_loss: 2.3933 - val_accuracy: 0.0839
```

This is just a warning, but it is clear that the model is not really improving and obviously it needs those gradients.

If I set cause_error=False I instead get the expected output (no warnings, modest improvements):

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 16us/sample - loss: 2.3671 - accuracy: 0.1527 - val_loss: 2.3445 - val_accuracy: 0.1508
Epoch 2/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 12us/sample - loss: 2.3293 - accuracy: 0.1596 - val_loss: 2.3072 - val_accuracy: 0.1610
Epoch 3/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 13us/sample - loss: 2.2939 - accuracy: 0.1683 - val_loss: 2.2722 - val_accuracy: 0.1720
Epoch 4/4
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 13us/sample - loss: 2.2609 - accuracy: 0.1784 - val_loss: 2.2397 - val_accuracy: 0.1847
```

I suspect I need to somehow tell Tensorflow to keep track of the gradients, but am not quite sure how. It seems to do it automatically when I use tf.matmul, and I'm pretty sure this kind of code used to work in TF 1.

The specific code I used to execute was (adapted from the mnist tutorial):

```
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 4

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()


x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows* img_cols)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows*img_cols)
input_shape = (img_rows * img_cols)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

dummy_layer = FCLayer(10, cause_error = True)
model.add( dummy_layer )
model.add( tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax') )

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is related to eager execution TF 2.0 -- any operations such as `tf.reshape` are run the moment they are encountered. `build` is only called a single time for a given model. Now, what is happening is that you are creating a tensor `weights2`, which is a reshaped version of the `tf.Variable` `weights` but is *not* itself a `tf.Variable` (ops generally return tensors, not variables). Because this happens in eager execution, no "record" of this is kept and `weights2` has no connection to `weights`. Thus, when it is used in the model call, `weights` cannot be updated. This does not happen in the `else` case because here, `weights2` is just another name referring to the actual `tf.Variable` `weights`.

Two way of fixing this:

1. Use `assign` in `build` to do the reshape in place (note, I use `self.w` because `self.weights` is a reserved name for Keras layers):

   ```
   def build(self,input_shape): 
       self.input_size = input_shape[1]        
       self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(self.input_size,
                                             self.output_size),
                                      initializer='random_normal',
                                      trainable=True)

       if self.cause_error:
           self.w.assign(tf.reshape(self.w,
                                      shape = (self.input_size,
                                               self.output_size)))
   ```

This causes no error/warning, but it might not be what you want because you are modifying the original `weights`, which is lost. I suppose you want to rather use a modified version of `weights` on each call. In this case, do it in the `call` method:

```
class FCLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,output_size,cause_error = False):
        super(FCLayer,self).__init__()
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.cause_error = cause_error

    def build(self,input_shape): 
        self.input_size = input_shape[1]        
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(self.input_size,
                                          self.output_size),
                                   initializer='random_normal',
                                   trainable=True)
    def call(self, inputs):
        weights2 = tf.reshape(self.w, (self.input_size, self.output_size)
        return tf.matmul(inputs, weights2)
```

This works because now the `reshape` operation is part of the model call graph, i.e. we can backtrace that `weights2` actually came from `weights`, and gradients can flow.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful, both in fixing my issue, but also in helping me understand how Tensorflow handles these things. I didn't realize that operations performed in build weren't included in the model call graph (I guess the name should have been a clue).

Answer (score 0):

Likely cause of that behaviour is lack of [@tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) decorator on the `build` function, i.e.

```
@tf.function
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.input_size = input_shape[1]
    weights = self.add_weight(shape=(self.input_size,
                                     self.output_size),
                              initializer='random_normal',
                              trainable=True)

    if self.cause_error:
        self.weights2 = tf.reshape(weights,
                                   shape=(self.input_size,
                                          self.output_size))
    else:
        self.weights2 = weights
```

Why is it vital? The Python Tensorflow API is just an interface to the actual implementation in C/C++. The moment you provide your custom operation (like `tf.reshape`) in Python to be executed as part of the graph, you have to instruct the module to compile this part of the code into "native" Tensorflow.

It doesn't matter that your `reshape` didn't actually reshape anything. You have "interrupted" default execution path and "injected" Python code. `@tf.function` should fix it.

Comment: `tf.function` has nothing to do with gradient flow. `tf.reshape` is not a "custom operation" but a built-in tensorflow function. By your logic (if I don't misunderstand your answer), no model should ever work without `tf.function` because they all use many `tf.some_operation` functions under the hood. Actually, adding `tf.function` as you proposed results in an error for me (very deeply nested so I'd rather not post it).

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I believe you are on the right track -- the issue is most likely related to eager execution and `tf.function` would deactivate it, which in principle would fix it. Sorry if I came across as rude -- but your solution still doesn't quite work, unfortunately.

Comment: @xdurch0 Not at all, I appreciate critical attitude :). Thanks for sharing the solution +1.